# error in download data from S3 'requester pay' bucket using hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, jets3t

I was using Hadoop 1.2.0 with command distcp to download a data from a S3 'requester pay' bucket, I have valid aws id and key, however, it went to an error, as shown below.

org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/dataset' XML Error Message: `AccessDenied`Access Denied4FDSDFS454DDWzToSESDFkzv+eiJBmRbqBkW0iWeOcSDFSD834SDFWE923UBzfMiyGXYXeX

I have tried many approaches: upgrade jets3t to the latest version, and also follow this post (http://www.mail-archive.com/user@pig.apache.org/msg03395.html) for configuration (however, which doesn't work).

But, none works. Does anyone how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have read permission on the folder/file which you are trying to access ?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission, since I can download the data successfully using s3cmd. However, it fails when using jets3t.